# Openrefine working with Templating to export JSON as records

Tags: etl, openrefine

I have been working with Openrefine for the last days trying to figure out how to export a Google Data sheet into a JSON file.

I have the following data that I want to export to a JSON file.

```
id  first name  last name   friends first name  friends last name   family first name   family last name
1   James   Brown   Judy    Garland Mary    Brown
            John    Neverland   Marlene Brown
            Paul    Garland Judy    Brown
2   John    Buller  Amy Garland Francis Buller
            Peter   Flake   John    Buller
            Jules   Peter   Judy    Buller
```

The JSON that I'm expecting is:

```
    {
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "James",
      "lastName": "Brown",
      "has": {
        "friends": [
          {
            "firstName": "Judy",
            "lastName": "Garland"
          },
          {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Neverland"
          },
          {
            "firstName": "Paul",
            "lastName": "Garland"
          }
        ],
        "family": [
          {
            "firstName": "Mary",
            "lastName": "Brown"
          },
          {
            "firstName": "Marlene",
            "lastName": "Brown"
          },
          {
            "firstName": "Judy",
            "lastName": "Brown"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Buller",
      "has": {
        "friends": [
          {
            "firstName": "Amy",
            "lastName": "Garland"
          },
          {
            "firstName": "Peter",
            "lastName": "Flake"
          },
          {
            "firstName": "Jules",
            "lastName": "Peter"
          }
        ],
        "family": [
          {
            "firstName": "Francis",
            "lastName": "Buller"
          },
          {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Buller"
          },
          {
            "firstName": "Judy",
            "lastName": "Buller"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So far I have tried several approaches:

1) using excel-to-json but it's limited to single nesting and it has some limitations as to column names

2) using Openrefine and the Templating tool but I have encountered several issues:
- Although they are detected as records in openrefine, you export rows and not records so it will export 6 rows to JSON, 4 of them containing empty data
- If i try filling down columns it will aso export 6 rows to JSON, 4 of them with duplicates thus loosing the relations between the person and his family members and friends

Any help would be much appreciated as I'm trying to export about 150,000 records of this type that have to be in this JSON format.

Answer (score 2):

OpenRefine only support one level of nesting. You might need to go with a programming language or an ETL solution to have nested element.